# receiver tag in the manifest twice

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-appwidget

I am trying create app widget according the tutorial on this website http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Creating-a-Home-Screen-App-Widget-on-Android-3833306.htm

but I am confused why there are two almost the same receiver tags in the manifest. Could somebody explain the reason please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mamlambo.imageswidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ImagesWidgetConfiguration"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="ImagesWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="ImagesWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                    <data android:scheme="images_widget" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: i didn't see both...anyways ..if so then delete one. its a mistake.

Comment: there are two receivers with the same name ImagesWidgetProvider but second one has data tag added with android:scheme="images_widget". If I delete the first (which I think is useless) the widget doesn't work.

Comment: no need to use scheme for simple widget.. no problem if you delete one.

Comment: @RanjitPati If I delete the first receiver tag the widget doesn't show in the widgets list but If I delete the second one (with android:scheme) the appwidget works ok. Thank you Ranjit Pati.

Answer (score 0):

May be your correct codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mamlambo.imageswidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ImagesWidgetConfiguration"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="ImagesWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                    <data android:scheme="images_widget" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/imageswidget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

It will be worked. hopefully

Comment: I have already developed my appwidget and I had to use both receivers in the manifest to make the appwidget working. I don't know why they both had to be present in the manifest but maybe I will find out later.

Comment: plz accept symbol click to earn 10 reputation. Please  it will be help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot accept your answer because it's not the correct one.